# How to do error handling from .config block using httpProvider - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I would like to intercept all http error messages and give the user visual feedback. For this, I want to do something like this

```
.config(function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
    return {
     'responseError': function(rejection) {
        // show visual feedback or emit an event.
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    ...
```

However, I can't inject `$rootScope` (to do a `$rootScope.$emit()`) since this is a **config** block. Nor is it possible to inject angular-growl or similar package, for the same reasons. How does one address this use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inject $rootScope together with $q:

```
.config(function($httpProvider) {
   $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $rootScope) {
   return {
    'responseError': function(rejection) {
      // show visual feedback or emit an event.
      $rootScope.$emit( ... );
      return $q.reject(rejection);
```

Comment: Thankyou - I missed that; was trying to inject $rootScope along with $httpProvider in the .config() line, and got the error.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
angular.module('interceptor.http', [])
    .config(function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('errorInterceptor');
    })
    .factory('errorInterceptor', function ($q, $rootScope) {
        return function (promise) {
            return promise.then(function (response) { },
             function (response) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast("error",{statusCode : 'error'});
                return $q.reject(response);
            });
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

... You can inject `$rootScope`. I don't know what you're talking about. However, if you'd like to inject dependencies at run-time that would otherwise require a service that would create a circular dependency, you can use the `$injector` service within config blocks like so:

```
// ... other angular code
.config(function($httpProvider){
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $injector){
    return {
      responseError: function(arg1, arg2, argWhatever){
        // This isn't run until there's actually an error (everything has already been configured)
        // This is totally allowed
        $http = $injector.get('$http');

        // ... do whatever with your service

        return $q.reject(/*something here*/);
      }
    };
  });
});
```